# Improving SQL Substring Extraction

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a working version of an extraction step, that seems quite lengthy and I was curious if there's a simpler approach that I may be missing. I've seen SUBSTRING_INDEX() referenced in other questions on the forum, however, that function isn't recognized in my version of Sql Server Management Studio.

I have a string that looks like this: Make\Model\Trim\New

I'd like to extract only the "Trim" from this string. Essentially, extract the substring between the last backslash and the second-to-last backslash.

Because the string length and number of backslashes may vary, I can't simply say "After the second and third backslashes". Below is my currently working code.

```
Select
 REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
     REVERSE(CAR_DESC),
     CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(CAR_DESC))+1,
     CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(CAR_DESC),CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(CAR_DESC))+1)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(CAR_DESC))-1
     )) AS TEST1
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: The SQL string manipulation functions are _deliberately awkward_ to use, in order to encourage doing this kind of work in client code or tooling instead of in the database. Also, they have significant variations depending on exactly what database you're using... and _don't say you're using Management Studio_. That's like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because it's the name you see on the dashboard radio.

Comment: You're storing separate pieces of data together in a single string; if you store your data more properly, you don't have to build such cumbersome and awkward expressions to break them apart. If the second-last substring is important, why don't you also store that in its own column _at write time_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option using JSON

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Make\Model\Trim\New')
 
Select A.[SomeCol]
       ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
       ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
 From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([SomeCol],'json'),'\\','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol               Pos1  Pos2    Pos3    Pos4
Make\Model\Trim\New   Make  Model   Trim    New
```

**Note:**  I had to escape the backslash, thus the `\\`

---

**IF FOUR elements (and no more)**, you can use `parsename()`

```
Select A.[SomeCol]
       ,Pos3 = parsename(replace(SomeCol,'\','.'),2)
 From  @YourTable A
```

Comment: Parsename() seems to work in this current instance, however, there appears to be instances where there are 5 or more backslashes...I'll mark as the answer, as this solution solves for the above example. However, it seems as though I may just be better off sticking with my current code. Appreciate the input/thought.

Comment: @2020db9. Correct,  more than four will return a NULL

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - As pointed out in the comments, this will only work with SQL Server 2022 or Azure.

You could do something still pretty ugly with string_split:

```
select
reverse(value) from (
select * from
STRING_SPLIT(reverse('Make\Model\Trim\New'), '\',1)
)t where
ordinal = 2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/29DZ4s_N)

You'd be a lot better off storing your data appropriately, as opposed to doing this kind of stuff every time you read the data.

Comment: Just a note: SQL Server 2022+ or Azure SQL Database / MI only.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in charge of data management and am too far downstream to have any say in how data is stored/structured. It would be exponentially easier if these strings were broken out into columns by delimiters. I'm sure I'll be waiting forever for that. String_split() seems to be a valid function in my current version, however, it doesn't like how I'm applying it when I try your code. Saying "string_split has too many arguments specified"

Comment: Yep, that means you're not running a version of sql recent enough to have the ordinal argument, so unfortunately this solution won't work.

Comment: If you're on a version prior to 2022, the last argument (the 1, which means return the ordinal) isn't supported.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit of a hack (to say the least) but as long as your string isn't really long, and you have fewer than 4 delimiters, you can hack out the pieces using `parsename()`. [parsename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a function designed for extracting parts of a fully qualified object name (e.g. `server.database.table.schema` or lower cardinality versions of the same).

The hack you can do is replace all the slashes in your string with periods, and then extract the names.

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'make\model\trim\new'

select @str = replace(@str, '\', '.')
select
    p1 = parsename(@str, 1),
    p2 = parsename(@str, 2),
    p3 = parsename(@str, 3),
    p4 = parsename(@str, 4)
```

Be warned however, if any individual part is longer than 128 characters (i.e. the length of a `sysname` object) *all* parts will return null (At least I think that's how it works. truthfully, you might want to play around with different lengths of total strings and string parts if you're concerned about either being fairly long).

e.g., this works, but if you make one of the strings longer, it fails:

```
declare @str nvarchar(1000) = concat(replicate('a', 128), '\', replicate('b', 128), '\', replicate('c', 128), '\', replicate('d', 128))

select @str = replace(@str, '\', '.')
select len(@str)
select
    p1 = parsename(@str, 1),
    p2 = parsename(@str, 2),
    p3 = parsename(@str, 3),
    p4 = parsename(@str, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the game, but here is an exact solution for your scenario.

> I'd like to extract only the "Trim" from this string. Essentially,
> extract the substring between the last backslash and the
> second-to-last backslash.

It is using XML and XQuery, and will work on any version starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is *tokenizing* input as XML.
- Trim is retrieved based on a sequential position via XPath predicate: `/root/r[last() - 1]`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CAR_DESC VARCHAR(100));  
INSERT INTO @tbl (CAR_DESC) VALUES 
('Make\Model\Trim\New'),
('Make\Model\Category\Trim\New'),
('Make\Model\Category\Sub-Category\Trim\New');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '\';

SELECT t.* 
    , c.value('(/root/r[last() - 1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Trim]
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(CAR_DESC, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | CAR_DESC | Trim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Make\Model\Trim\New | Trim |
| 2 | Make\Model\Category\Trim\New | Trim |
| 3 | Make\Model\Category\Sub-Category\Trim\New | Trim |